# Angular - How do I unit test a function inside an rxjs 6 operator using jasmine so that it shows up as covered in istanbul?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, rxjs6, istanbul

How do I get the code inside the skipWhile to show as covered by istanbul? I'm using Angular, jasmine and rxjs 6. It can be a completely trivial test as long as the coverage stat shows its covered.

```
ngOnInit() {      
this.claimSubscription = this.store.pipe(select(ClaimStoreSelectors.selectClaim),
         skipWhile(
            clm =>
               clm.claimId !== this.route.snapshot.params['id']
         ))
         .subscribe(claim => {
//unimportant for the question
      });
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? We can't be the ones to do your work for you. Show some effort man

Answer (score 0):

Answer was to extract the contents of skipWhile into its own function, then istanbul doesn't complain about it. I never figured out the original question, but this solution will do.